# How to figure out whats the width and height of a text box in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do you figure out the size of a text box in Photoshop?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply keeping open the Infobox panel, and having the settings of photoshop to deal with px measurement instead than cm/mm or inches.

Answer (score 2):

With the text layer selected his command+t. This will open the transform tool. The dimensions of the text box will appear at the top of the screen under the object details.